# Визуализация графов

Tags: c#, winforms

На просторах интернета нашёл код, который визуализирует графы. Вот пост на хабре - https://habrahabr.ru/post/116758/
Взял оттуда код и решил на форме попробовать сделать такое чудо (прич1м и для работы может пригодиться). Создал проект WinForms, завёл класс, как в посте, а в файле Form1.cs написал так:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Blue,4F);
        PointF[] points = new PointF[] { new PointF(60, 50), new PointF(20, 30), new PointF(80, 15) };
        Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();


        GraphicsExtension.DrawBSpline(graphics, pen, points, 0.81F, 0.1F);
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что при компиляции, почему-то появляется пустая форма, хотя должны же появиться лини.
Есть мысли, почему так?

Comment: поместите код отрисовки в событие Paint

Comment: @Igor Спасибо большое, получилось!

Comment: @Igor Может вы знаете как сделать такое на `Canvas` в wpf? Просто там я не могу понять как `CreateGraphics ` вызвать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В WPF по простому : в Canvas вставляете

```
<Polyline Stroke="LightBlue" StrokeThickness="4" 
     Points="10,150 30,140 50,170 70,120 90"></Polyline>
```

Если требуется сложная фигура то можно воспользоваться:

```
<Path Stroke="DarkGoldenRod" StrokeThickness="3"   
Data="M 100,200 C 100,25 400,350 400,175 H 280" />
```

Comment: А если через код делать?

Comment: Например так:
            `var pl = new Polyline
            {
                Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue),
                StrokeThickness = 3,
                Points = new PointCollection
                {
                    new Point(10,150),
                    new Point(30,140),
                    new Point(50,170),
                    new Point(70,120)
                }
            };
            MyCanvas.Children.Add(pl);`

Comment: @Андрей Нет, вы не поняли, мне надо реализовать метод, а не просто взять и добавить `Polyline` на `Canvas`

Comment: И что конкретно не получается? Код для winforms у вас есть. Добавляйте точки в polyline по уже имеющемуся алгоритму

Comment: @Андрей Да вы правы, спасибо за информацию